# Data getting lost during shut down of app, how to save in shared preferences android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, shutdown

I have a bunch of products in my app and when the user purchases the products, the product count gets updated but if I shut down the app and restart it again, the product count gets lost. Currently, I'm saving the data in a document but I came across `sharedpreferences` which I feel like is a better way to save the data for the app. I would like to know how can I save the data and read it again. Would this be a better approach to save the data and not lose it.

```
    private void saveInterimStocks() {
        InterimStockDao dao = new InterimStockDao(CouchManager.OPERATIONAL_DB, AirFiUtils.getOperationalDatabaseIndexMap());
// saving the data in StockCarryForward Document - JSON doc
        StockCarryForward stock = new StockCarryForward();
        if (getFlightLegSubscription().isPresent()) {
            stock.setFlightKey(getFlightLegSubscription().get().getFlightMetadata().getFlightKey());
        }
        if (getFlightLegIdentifier().isPresent()) {
            stock.setFli(getFlightLegIdentifier().get());
        }
        stock.setStockMap(AirFiApplication.getStockMap());
        dao.createOrUpdate(stock);
    }
```

If I logout of the app and then shutdown and restart it, the data is not lost. Only if I shut down without logging out, the data gets lost.

```
 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (getAirlineProfile().isAutomaticLogoutEnabled()) {
            stopLogoutTimer();
        }
        if (getAirlineProfile().isStocksEnabled()) {
            saveInterimStocks();
        }
    }
```

Here is the `onStop()` of the activity where the method gets called.

Comment: Shared Preferences is suitable for small amounts of key/value pairs.  If your data isn't key/value pairs, it isn't small, or you want to perform operations more complex than read and write (like search) it isn't suitable.

Comment: If you are keeping track of products already purchased, you should not keep it in SharedPreferences. Instead consider keeping it inside a web service.

Comment: replace `onStop` with `onPause`, it might work.

Comment: if your data is structured then you should use SQlite Database to store .